# 500 Internal server error while trying to consume webmethod from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

Ive got asmx handler file with cs class.

When I enter mysite/myService.asmx?op=Test nice page is rendered and I can invoke my web method without any problems but when I try to do it from javascript I can see in firebug 500 error as a responce. I put breakpoint on the server side inside that web.method but it wasnt even invoked.

what am I doing wrong ?

Class Declaration:

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public partial class WebServiceDB : System.Web.Services.WebService {

Web.Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Test()
{
    return "test";
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "mysite/myService.asmx?op=Test",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert("ok");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

When you enter a URL in the browser, you are performing a GET request. However, your `$.ajax` request is using POST. Given the lack of much other context, that would be my first suspicion as where the problem is. Try changing `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"`

Comment: Hey. If it was a "Method not allowed" exception it would have been a 405 error, I think.